# LACP can load balance by data source?

Tags: switch, lacp

**Backgroud**
I use a 2012 iMac and a 2012 Mac mini with two thunderbolt to ethernet adaptor make Link aggregation with the help of switch-CISCO SG200-08.

**Problem**
LACP both OK on two of my Mac.When transfer big file Network speed can reach 225MB/S
But the real READ/WRITE speed is only 110MB/S(both of my macs use ssd)

**Question**
I seem to know that Link aggregation can only balance load by IP or MAC address?
Can I make two mac reach 2Gbps transfer speed(transferring  before separating data to two network port)?

Answer (score 1):

Transfering files is not always the best idea to measure the network bandwidth as it's limited by read-write speed to the disk. Try using the [iperf](http://mac.softpedia.com/get/Network-Admin/Iperf.shtml) tool to measure the network bandwidth first.

Comment: hi，Guardian.the limitation is on not my disks(I mentioned already).LACP can only load balance by MAC or IP addresses,so LACP can not seperate a file to two network cable point to one MAC or IP address(as you know,LACP aggregate two IPs and MACs to one)

Comment: Why don't you just try iperf?

Comment: Your SSDs cannot go at 2Gbps, or even 1Gbps. The disk is the bottleneck.